# Firestore not picking up in xcode even though it connects (reads/writes) to my database

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-firestore

Good day guys,

I am not sure if anyone has ever come across this problem but I would like to understand what is happening.

Firestore functions were changing colour as you'd expect untill I clean-built my project. After that none of the functions were picking up in Xcode 11.5 giving me this error: **Use of unresolved identifier 'Firestore'**

However, the strange thing is that my project still builds and runs despite the error and I am still able to read/write to my Firestore database.

Is this an issue with my xcode, is there a way to fix this because it is so confusing to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of color change means that your IDE is not recognizing the firestore functions as an included library, and the error message means that there is no firestore defined, so most probably you need to import the firestore library somewhere.